# CPU Usage Spikes to 100%

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to dynamically get data xml from the other server for every 15 seconds. Then convert the xml data into json and save it into a new file on my server.

Here my jquery code:

```
(function($){
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

    var refreshData = setInterval(getData, 15000);

    getData();
})(jQuery);
```

Here the code in data.php file.

```
// load class
<?php
require_once 'class/rii.class.php';

// get data
$data = new RII_Data( 'http://theotherservertoget/pri2.xml' );

// generate json
$data->generate_json();
```

And here the code in rii.class.php file.

```
<?php
class RII_Data {
    private $options = array();

    function __construct(  $url = '' ) {
        $this->options['url'] = $url;
    }

    private function get_json( $url ) {
        $xml_string = @file_get_contents( $url );
        $xml_string = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $xml_string );
        $xml_string = trim (str_replace( '"', "'", $xml_string ) );
        $xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml_string );
        $json = json_encode( $xml );
        return $json;
    }

    private function print_json( $json ) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $json;
        exit;
    }

    public function generate_json() {
        $json = $this->get_json( $this->options['url'] );
        $this->print_json( $json );
    }
}
```

And my server always down after running the js, 
did I make mistake?

Comment: why do you think anything is wrong? do you want a script that does not fully use available resources?

Comment: Yes Dagon, I wan't a script that does  not fully use resoureces. But, I'm not expert about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var refreshData = setInterval(getData, 15000);
```

You are using eager loading method to refresh your page every 15 secs. I think that's the problem causing your web server to consume lot of resource.
You should just update what has been changed instead of re-convert all the xml to json.
Edited: The simplexml convert whole xml tree into objects which will consume a lot of resource. If you can get rid of it, using string manipulating function to get the job done, it will be better. 
Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think refresh the page and write the data into a new file for every 15 secs causing the problem. I have fixed the code, thanks.